# C# Download sub folders from FTP site

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp

I am attempting to download all folders from an ftp site. I have started by using SSIS but it can't do this out of the box and I need to use script tasks. I still cannot find an example of how to achieve this;

The FTP base-folder which I connect to contains a number of folders. Each folder contains only files. I need to replicate this structure locally (a folder with many folders in.. each of which have some files).

```
BaseFolder
    ->Folder1
    ->Folder2
         ->File1
         ->File2
    ->FolderN
```

How can I do this via FTP? Ideally within SSIS. All the solutions i've found can sometimes traverse the FTP sub-folders but ends up downloading all files in to the same master directory.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Have you looked at [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20528295/4707373) may also help you